# Scroll list item one by one - html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a `list tag` where only one `list item` will be appearing on clicking on the `up` and `down` arrow.
 I actually figured out how to make it after a long struggle.

I have `5` list items. Third one will  be visible on page load. When I click `up` arrow, I get the `second` and `first` list item. But if I click again for the 3rd time everything is going invisible.

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6e3Z/).

Also please help me on adding a `transition` effect to it. When I click the `up` or `down` arrow. It's appearing instantly. Instead I want to be appeared smoothly.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to check if it is the last/first element, because there will not be next for last elem and prev for first elem

Comment: here,  try this http://jsfiddle.net/m6e3Z/4/

Comment: If i want to add `transition` to it. I need to apply it on `li` or `a`? I guess `-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in` this is what we need to use.

Comment: When li tags shows five and if you then click next, do you want to see one or not to do anything on next click?

Comment: @tilda - Answer you've provided is what I was looking for. But now i need to add transition to it. But I don't have any clue on where or how to do it. Help me in that please.

Comment: @Son - again your edit is using code markup for things that simply aren't code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cur = 2;
$(function() {
    $('.up').click(function() {
        if(cur <= 0) return;
        var last = cur;
        cur --;
        $('.dropdown li').eq(last).addClass('hide');
        $('.dropdown li').eq(cur).css('margin-top', '-5px').removeClass('hide');
        $('.dropdown li').eq(cur).animate({marginTop: '0px'}, 'slow', function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hide');
        });

    });

    $('.down').click(function() {
        if(cur >= $('.dropdown li').length - 1) return;
        var last = cur;
        cur ++;
        $('.dropdown li').eq(last).addClass('hide');
        $('.dropdown li').eq(cur).css('margin-top', '5px').removeClass('hide');
        $('.dropdown li').eq(cur).animate({marginTop: '0px'}, 'slow', function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hide');
        });
    });
});
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/m6e3Z/9/)

Answer (score 0):

It was because of removal off all active class when reached on top/bottom.Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.up').click(function() {
    if($('.active').length==0)
            $('.dropdown li:last-child').removeClass('hide').addClass('active');    
        else    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('hide').prev().removeClass('hide').addClass('active')
})

$('.down').click(function() {
if($('.active').length==0)
            $('.dropdown li:first').removeClass('hide').addClass('active'); 
        else    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('hide').next().removeClass('hide').addClass('active')
})
});
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6e3Z/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6e3Z/5/)

Add class to first li tag.

```
<li class="first">First</li>
```

if active li tag has that class, don't do anything.

```
 if(!($('.active').hasClass('first'))){ 

$('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('hide').prev().removeClass('hide').addClass('active');
                                             }
```